# How to preallocate datatime array in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, datetime

I would like to compute long datetime array in Matlab and hence wishing to preallocate it. Unfortunately when I am using `NaT`, I am loosing time component:

```
>> [datetime(1441411200,'ConvertFrom','posixtime'), datetime(1441411500,'ConvertFrom','posixtime')]
ans = 
  1×2 datetime array
   05-Sep-2015 00:00:00   05-Sep-2015 00:05:00

>> A=NaT(2,1)
A = 
  2×1 datetime array
   NaT
   NaT

>> A(1)=datetime(1441411200,'ConvertFrom','posixtime'); A(2)=datetime(1441411500,'ConvertFrom','posixtime');
>> A
A = 
  2×1 datetime array
   05-Sep-2015
   05-Sep-2015
```

How to accomplish?

---

Matlab version is `2016b`

Comment: It works fine for me. Which edition of Matlab do you use? One solution could be to work your way backward, i.e. without having `A` defined run `A(2)=datetime(1441411500,'ConvertFrom','posixtime');` (this will create the vector), `A(1)=datetime(1441411200,'ConvertFrom','posixtime');` (which then fills the first entry)

Comment: Matlab version is `2016b`

Comment: Then that shouldn't be the problem. Did the other suggestion work?

Comment: @NickyMattsson I did by reordering steps: first I made array of posix timestamps and then converting it to datetime in bulk

Comment: That is of course also a solution, but with reverse order of assigning `A` the first entry will preallocate `A`, and it will thus be similar to preallocating with `A=NaT(2,1)`.

Comment: But this requires to compute in reverse order

Comment: Fill the array in a reverse order and then use `flipud` to flip it. I.e. compute as your have been doing the entire time, but map the first result to `A(end)`, the second to `A(end-1)` and so on and then flip the array when you are done. (end is here the number of the last entry, not the function `end`)

Comment: Yes, but all these are workarounds. The question is, what is happening in my original approach? Is it a bug in `2016b`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only problem here is in the `Format` property of the array created by `NaT` - it gets a different default value. So, you could do:

```
A = NaT(2, 1);
A.Format = 'dd-MMM-uuuu HH:mm:ss';
A(1) = datetime()
```

which results in

```
A = 
  2×1 datetime array
   30-Apr-2018 10:34:47
   NaT
```